# Override phtml from third party extension in theme folder

Tags: magento2, extensions, template-override

I have an extension installed via composer and wish to make some small changes so it fits better within my theme. The file is located at:

`/vendor/<Namespace>/<Module>/view/frontend/templates/file.phtml.`

I understand I can copy this file to my theme and override it without making xml updates. I just can't get the folder right where it should live.

I have tried following the official magento guide and other posts on here but it's not updating:

```
/<theme_dir>/<Namespace>_<Module>/templates/file.phtml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood about Namespace_Module.

You need to get this value in the module’s registration.php file.

For example, an extension is located in `<magento dir>/vendor/magetu/checkout-module`. You need to get the value Namespace_Module in `<magento dir>/vendor/magetu/checkout-module/registration.php`

```
<?php

use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Magetu_Checkout', __DIR__);
```

Your phtml override file should be located in `<theme_dir>/Magetu_Checkout/templates/file.phtml`

Comment: You are correct Tu. using the correct details from the registration file kicked it into action straight away. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You’re welcome @AndyS

Answer (score 1):

The full path should be:
`app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/<Namespace>_<Module>/templates/file.phtml`

HTH, Tom

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply Tom, this is actually where I put the files, just me shortening the theme folder name